# Surround a div with left, right and bottom div's

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issue with a **video div that will have a responsive width**.

There's 3 images that need to stick to the video element

- green (left side)
- orange (right side)
- red (bottom side)

The issue's is that

- If I make it one big background image it will be stretched and the arrows lose it's aspect ratio.

[image]

How could I go about achieving this effects? Whilst keeping full responsiveness.

Comment: will I get a pro psychic certificate if I tell you how to do it without seeing your code? Joking aside, can you provide some code?

Comment: There is no code yet. I'm looking for general ideas :)

Comment: How you know the arrows will lose aspect ratio if you have not tried any code yet! 0_O

Comment: Well that's obvious right? If you stretch an image with an aspect ratio.. and the height stays the same, but the width changes? The arrows will be squashed on the x-axis

Comment: "There is no code yet. I'm looking for general ideas :)". Well based on the question tags, you've identified you need to use CSS. Try starting there. As it stands, with no code, the question is too broad. We don't even know how you want the video to behave responsively, so we can't say how to build the other elements around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This presents an interesting challenge. I'm sure others have written something potentially more useful. I just wanted to practice my written communication skills.

I discovered a method to help with your question:https://codepen.io/viewtifulmoejoe/pen/yPvQmz?editors=1100

I'm putting in this code to fulfill the code requirement of SO.

```
<div class="viewer_component">
  <div class="viewer_component__bgImg">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rQmri0X.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="viewer_component__video">
   <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/854x480" alt="" class="viewer_component__video--src">
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

- I used this image to prototype a method: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jLZD.jpg
  The black outline serves as the imaginary frame around the video similar to the image you posted.
- I used a placeholder image to imitate the video and used the dimensions of a traditional youtube video.

The method requires that the imaginary frame in the background image match the ratio of the video container. This is the only way I know to make the the effect work as expected without plugins/libraries/javascript.

Please let me know if this helps you with this challenge. Any questions, I'm happy to oblige.

A more scalable method would be to have multiple images saved out. 1 for the left/top/right/bottom of the video container and position them relative to the video. This method requires a bit of finesse.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be too hard using either `flexbox` or `display: table;`. Take a look at the following example:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.container div {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div style="flex: 0;">
    <iframe width="300" height="100"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

The red bar at the bottom is just a block element. You could use background images to apply the image patterns.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do it:

- Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- Use `display: table;`, `display: table-row`, `display:table-cell` to build a table out of divs
- Use tables